# Java BigDecimal alternative library

Tags: java, bigdecimal, gcj

This may strike as particularly odd but I must compile several new code against GCJ; that doesn't support Java's BigDecimal.

What I'm looking for is an alternative to java.math.BigDecimal.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks!

Comment: What exactly is GCJ? If it doesn't support some parts of standard Java API, how can you be sure it'll support your new library?

Comment: Are you sure that gcj doesn't support parts of the *standard* Java API? This sounds more like a library issue that an issue with gcj.

Comment: @Nikita GCJ is the Gnu Compiler for Java - http://gcc.gnu.org/java/ - it's actually a pain in the ass and I really don't know if it will support or not the new library, but if it's totally encapsulated (the new library) and only uses Java 1.4 syntax I'll probably be safe.

Comment: @Frankie what version of gcj?

Comment: @Frankie what happens when you try to compile a program that uses `java.math.BigDecimal`?

Comment: @Vivin GCJ blows on some methods it doesn't support yet (GCJ has a semi-implementation of BigDecimal). On my particular case: `error: class 'java.math.BigDecimal' has no method named 'setScale' matching signature '(ILjava/math/RoundingMode;)Ljava/math/BigDecimal;'` thks

Comment: Have you tried taking the code for BigDecimal/BigInteger from Java 6 and compiling it with GCJ?

Comment: @Peter, actually yes, did try that prior to asking. All went kabum! :) Vivin's answer works great!

Comment: Taking code out of Apache Harmony might be better from a licensing perspective.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like gcj is compiling against JDK 1.4.2, which only provides `setScale(int scale, int roundingMode)` and `setScale(int scale)`.

The code you're trying to compile seems to have been written for JDK 1.5.0 and above. In JDK 1.5.0, you get `setScale(int newScale, RoundingMode roundingMode)` in addition to the other two.

You can see if there is an update to gcj that lets it use 1.5. From looking at the [gcj website](http://gcc.gnu.org/java/), I don't see this as the case. It says that the current version "supports most of the 1.4 libraries plus some 1.5 additions."

Your other option is to rewrite the code so that calls to `setScale(int newScale, RoundingMode roundingMode)` are replaced by `setScale(int scale, int roundingMode)`. In 1.5.0, instead of specifing an integer value for `roundingMode` (using the static ints in `BigDecimal`), you can specify it using the `RoundingMode` enum (the older method is still maintained for backwards compatibility).

So in your code, instead of `RoundingMode.CEILING`, you would use `BigDecimal.ROUND_CEILING`.

Comment: Vivin, works perfectly. Gonna have to do some changes but works great. Thanks!

Comment: @Frankie No problem. Pardon my initial incredulity. I haven't used gcj much, and so didn't know it was such a pain!